# jQTouch excute javascript code when going to next page

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, debugging, jqtouch

I have been working on an iPhone app that requires me to dynamically change the content. I have the following code:

```
       <div id="home">
       <div class="toolbar">
            <a class="blueButton" href="javascript: void(0);" onClick="$('#logout').show();">Logout</a>
            <h1>AllaccessMD</h1>
        </div>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <ul class="edgetoedge" id="ulHome"></ul>
    </div>
```

When this page gets called I call the javascript function:

```
function setupHome(){
if(localStorage.role == "Specialist"){
    var homeUL = '<li class="arrow"><a id="s,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#ePresentations">My E-Presentation</a></li>'
            + '<li class="arrow"><a id="s,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#date">My Newsletter</a></li>'
            + '<li class="arrow"><a id="s,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#date">My Events</a></li>'
            + '<li class="arrow"><a id="s,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#date">Medical Partners</a></li>'
            + '<li class="arrow"><a id="s,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#date">Search</a></li>'
            + '<li class="arrow"><a id="s,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#date">Profile</a></li>';
    $('#ulHome').html(homeUL);
} else {
    var homeUL = '<li class="arrow"><a id="m,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#date">Medical Partners</a></li>'
            + '<li class="arrow"><a id="m,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#date">Search</a></li>'
            + '<li class="arrow"><a id="m,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#date">Profile</a></li>';
    $('#ulHome').html(homeUL);
}

$('#ulHome li a').click(function(){
    alert('I dont see this alert on a iPhone!');
    if(this.href.search("#ePresentations") != 0) {
        var idObject = getID(this.id);
        setupEPresentation(idObject.id);
    }
});
```

}

This all works fine except the $('#ulHome li a').click() doesn't work.  It works fine on Firefox and Chrome, but not on a iPhone.

Where did I go wrong? OR is there a better way to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `tap` instead of `click`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tap instead of click, also the auto change page function is going to override your links since they have an href location.  Also I wouldn't mix javascript in the code with events in the javascript, so:

```
   <div id="home">
     <div class="toolbar">
        <a id="logoutButton" class="blueButton" href="#">Logout</a>
        <h1>AllaccessMD</h1>
     </div>
   <h1>Home</h1>
   <ul class="edgetoedge" id="ulHome"></ul>
   </div>
```

and

```
function setupHome(){
if(localStorage.role == "Specialist"){
    var homeUL = '<li class="arrow"><a class="Presentation" id="s,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#">My E-Presentation</a></li>'
            + '<li class="arrow"><a id="s,' + localStorage.userID + '" data="#">My Newsletter</a></li>'
            + '<li class="arrow"><a id="s,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#">My Events</a></li>'
            + '<li class="arrow"><a id="s,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#">Medical Partners</a></li>'
            + '<li class="arrow"><a id="s,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#">Search</a></li>'
            + '<li class="arrow"><a id="s,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#">Profile</a></li>';
    $('#ulHome').html(homeUL);
} else {
    var homeUL = '<li class="arrow"><a id="m,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#">Medical Partners</a></li>'
            + '<li class="arrow"><a id="m,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#">Search</a></li>'
            + '<li class="arrow"><a id="m,' + localStorage.userID + '" href="#">Profile</a></li>';
    $('#ulHome').html(homeUL);
}

$('#ulHome li a').tap(function(){
    alert('I dont see this alert on a iPhone!');
    if(this.hasClass("Presentations") ) {
        var idObject = getID(this.id);
        setupEPresentation(idObject.id);
    }
});

$('#logoutButton').tap(function() { 
   $('#logout').show();
});
```